# Is it possible to set Tooltip for each items of wxcombobox?

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets

I am using wxpython for GUI.I have a combobox with some items.

After setting list items , can we set tooltip for each items when mouse hover the item in the dropdown?

Also is it possible to give ellipse kind of style(...) with tooltip?

```
self.listItems = wx.ComboBox(self, -1, "", size=(280,-1)) 
self.listItems.SetItems(self.mainList[selectedList]['Items'])
```

Please suggest your thoughts.

Comment: remember you are not setting tooltip for the item - you are setting tooltip for the combo box. So when you change the item in the combobox, call SetTooltip( "my new tooltp" );

Comment: Are you telling we could not set tooltip for each item?

Comment: what do you mean "for each item"? when you change the selection in the combo box, you can catch the appropriate event and set the tooltip. if you mean something else - please clarify.